# Thumbs up or thumbs down on PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

what i'm basically trying to do is make a 'thumbs up' appear if the user scores >= to 2 and shows a 'thumbs down' if the user scores < 2

Here is the code i tried to use..

```
 <?php
//Recieves form..Form ID
$fid = $_GET['id'];

//Recieves answers
$answer1= $_POST['answerOne'];
$answer2= $_POST['answerTwo'];
$answer3= $_POST['answerThree'];
$score=0;
?>

<?php //Gets thumbs up if did well, gets thumbs down if not so good
    if ($score>=2){
        echo "<center><img src='Images/thumbsup.png' height='295' width='295' /> </center>";
    }
    elseif ($score<2) {
        echo "<center><img src='Images/thumbsdown.png' height='295' width='295' /> </center>";
    }
    ?>  

<body>

<!--Answers for Quiz 1-->   
    <?php 
    if ($fid == 1){

    if ($answer1 == "B") {$score++;}
    if ($answer2 == "B") {$score++;}
    if ($answer3 == "A") {$score++;}
    }
    ?>

    <?php 
    if ($fid == 1){
        echo "
        <p id='YourScore'> Your score is: </p>
        <p id='YourScore'>$score/3 correct answered </p>";}
    ?>
```

What happens is that it always show up 'thumbs down'. I think its because $score is equals to 0 and what its NOT doing is using the incremented value after adding the score as the value to use to define whether to give a thumbs up or down.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are setting your score AFTER you do something with it.. no wonder you get thumbs down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment: you calculate score after your thumbs, so turn those around:

```
<?php
    //Recieves form..Form ID
    $fid = $_GET['id'];

    //Recieves answers
    $answer1= $_POST['answerOne'];
    $answer2= $_POST['answerTwo'];
    $answer3= $_POST['answerThree'];
    $score=0;
?>

<body>
    <div id="Wrapper">  
        <div id="Container">
            <!--Answers for Quiz 1-->   
            <?php 
            if ($fid == 1) {

                if ($answer1 == "B") {$score++;}
                if ($answer2 == "B") {$score++;}
                if ($answer3 == "A") {$score++;}

            }
            ?>

            <?php 
            //Gets thumbs up if did well, gets thumbs down if not so good
            if ($score >= 2) {
                echo "<img src='Images/thumbsup.png' height='295' width='295' /> ";
            }
            elseif ($score < 2) {
                echo "<img src='Images/thumbsdown.png' height='295' width='295' /> ";
            }

            if ($fid == 1) {
                echo "<p id='YourScore'> Your score is: </p>
                      <p id='YourScore'>$score/3 correct answered </p>";
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: I've actually thought about this before, but the only thing is that I want the image BEFORE it shows the score. Do you suggest that I just use a Div to move it to where I like or do you have an alternative way?

Comment: Ive encountered another problem..because I'm using the same thumbs up, thumbs down for two different quiz, what ended up happening is that it duplicates the thumbs..(see updated code)

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you aren't checking the answers therefore the score will always be 0 and `elseif ($score<2)` will always be true.

You have to check if the answers where right BEFORE printing the 'thumbs'